# Will android market work (update app) after I install a new mod in my phone

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, updates, samsung-galaxy-apollo

I am going to root and install cyanogen mod 7 on my samsung I5801 (Having froyo).

Will the android market work in cyanogen mod i.e. will I be able to use and update all the applications (whenever updates are released) that I installed from android market as I would do previously?

Answer (score 3):

CyanogenMod is [not permitted to redistribute Google's proprietary apps](http://lifehacker.com/5367693/google-sends-cease-and-desist-to-cyanogenmod-android-hacker) packaged with the ROM, but they make them available separately. As long as you download and flash the latest [Google Apps package](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Latest_Version/Google_Apps) from your recovery system, you can continue to use the Market as you normally would.

The newest versions of CM are (according to the wiki, anyway) designed to actually backup your Google Apps during the install and then re-install them for you, but I've had mixed results with this so I typically just install them manually after installing CM.

Comment: Can I install the android market and related google apps (gmail, maps etc. etc.) with a backup apk file of it and update them accordingly using the market just the way I have been doing in past?

Comment: @GauravSharma: I think that can sometimes cause some weird force close issues, but you can try it and see if it works, certainly. I do think there are a few underlying Google frameworks that aren't present in CyanogenMod and are also installed by their Google Apps package, but I've never tried that myself so it's entirely possible that it would work.